# Django: wrong redirect

Tags: python, django, feincms

I have a server with two Django/FeinCMS backends. One is on a subdomain like sub.domain.com and the other on domain.com.

For each backend I created a page (one called "home", one called "frontpage") and told them to overwrite the url with "/".

Now I have a very strange problem:

Ca every 5min the frontpage of the subdomain works and the frontpage of the domain not. This behaviour changes after 5min so that the frontpage of the domain works and the frontpage of the subdomain doesn't.

I don't know where I should start to look for a mistake. Maybe someone of you had the same error and knows a solution.

Thanks for your help

Ps: By not working I mean that the user sees another page from the site when he goes to www.domain.com or sub.domain.com

PPs: in the subdomain settings.py I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    # main host
    'sub.domain.com',
)
```

And in the domain settgins.py I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    # main host
    '.domain.com',
    # alias hosts
    '.other-domain.com',
    '.other-domain2.com',
)
```

Might this be the problem?

Comment: how are you serving Django? I mean, what HTTP server are you using on front of it (Apache, nginx, etc.)? I think you might solve your problem in the HTTP server configuration rather than in Django settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a cache collision, because I used the same backend twice and just altered one of them.